# Simperium and Backbone Relationships

Tags: backbone.js, simperium

Simperium and Core Data relationships work fine, but what Backbone models do I need to create,  in order to sync models with relationships.

The Simperium Backbone todo example only uses one model, where can I find an example of a Backbone app using relationships and Simperium.

Thanks

EDIT:
I just want to know, if [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) or a similiar library is compatible with Simperium.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to map the relationships to your Backbone models. Each relationship will result in a list of unique identifiers that can be used to reference other models. You'll need to hook these up yourself though. Something like Backbone-relational could also work.

Note that the [full Simperium.js source code](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-js) is now available. I've also created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-js/issues/1) to clarify how relationships can work with Simperium.js and Backbone.